Is it possible to add 2 decimals in an ngModel?
I have an input with the variable name sipmaximum. This variable returns a numeric value.
For example
9999

template
<tr>
   <th>SIP maximum </th>
   <td>
      <input id="sipmaximum" name="sipmaximum" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="sipmaximum" style="width: 70%" required greaterThanZero />
   </td>
</tr>


Normally, the variable sipmaximum should display
9999.00

Here is the JSON
{
   "AANBOD": {
      "ISINAANBOD": "Y",
      "RISK": "3",
      "COMMENTAIRE_FR": "",
      "COMMENTAIRE_NL": "",
      "QTTE_TOTALE": 0,
      "QTTE_FAITE": 0,
      "QTTE_REST": 0,
      "QTTE_MIN": 100,
      "QTTE_MAX": 15000,
      "MULTIPLE": 0,
      "DATEVALID_DEBUT": "2019-09-16",
      "DATEVALID_FIN": "2050-12-31",
      "MARKET": "",
      "SIPAGENCEFLAG": "Y",
      "SIPCLIENTFLAG": "N",
      "SIPMINIMUM": 50,
      "SIPMAXIMUM": 9999
   }
}

How should I add the .00, please?
export class EditPurchasableSecuritiesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  svm: string;
  risk: string;
  datedeb: Date;
  datefin: Date;
  min: number;
  max: number;
  sipminimum: number;
  sipmaximum: number;

  TIT: Tit[] = [];

  constructor(
    private service: EditPurchasableSecuritiesService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let svm: string | null;
    svm = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("svm");
    if (!svm) {
      this.goBack();
      return;
    }
    this.svm = svm;
    this.editPurchasableSecuritiesManagement(this.svm);
    this.datedeb = new Date();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  editPurchasableSecuritiesManagement(svm: string): void {
    this.service
      .editPurchasableSecuritiesManagement(this.svm)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
          this.TIT = res.TIT;
          this.risk = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.RISK;
          this.datedeb = new Date();
          this.datefin = new Date(res.TIT[0].AANBOD.DATEVALID_FIN);
          this.min = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.QTTE_MIN;
          this.max = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.QTTE_MAX;
          this.sipminimum = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.SIPMINIMUM;
          this.sipmaximum = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.SIPMAXIMUM;
        }
      });
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  updatePurchasableSecuritiesManagement(): void {
    this.service
      .updatePurchasableSecuritiesManagement(
        this.svm,
        this.risk,
        this.datedeb,
        this.datefin,
        this.min,
        this.max,
        this.sipminimum,
        this.sipmaximum
      )
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
          this.router
            .navigateByUrl("/", { skipLocationChange: true })
            .then(() => {
              this.router.navigate([
                "functional-management/list-purchasable-securities",
              ]);
            });
        }
      });
  }
}

Interface
export interface PurchasableSecuritieResponse extends ApiResponse {
    TIT: Tit[];
  }
  
  export interface Tit {
    ADVTITRE: {
      BASIQUETITRE: {
        SVM: number;
        ISIN: string;
        STOCK: string;
        LABEL: string;
        PLACE: number;
        PLACELABEL: string;
        REGR: number;
        REGRLABEL: string;
        DEVISE: string;
        COURS: {
          DATE: string;
          TIME: string;
          VALUE: number;
          HIGH: number;
          LOW: number;
          CLOTURE: number;
        };
      };
      EXIST: number;
      SECE: number;
      SECE_LIB: string;
      PAYS: number;
      PAYS_LIB: string;
      YPMAR: string;
      CUM: string;
      DEVCP: string;
      CPPX: number;
      DATCPN: string;
      COURG: number;
      DCOURG: string;
      COURB: number;
      DCOURB: string;
      CODEF: number;
      ECHEANCE: string;
      RADIATION: string;
      COTATION: string;
      RATING: string;
      COURUS: number;
      BRUT: number;
      ECH1: string;
      ECH2: string;
      ECH3: string;
      ECH4: string;
      ECH5: string;
      TAUX1: number;
      TAUX2: number;
      TAUX3: number;
      TAUX4: number;
      TAUX5: number;
      HYPERLINK: string;
      INFOBOU: number;
      HISTCOURS: number;
      GROUPE: string;
      COUPON: number;
      WARRANT: number;
      OPTION: number;
      REVERSE: number;
      RECO: number;
      SIGNAUX: number;
    };
    TITARG: {
      COMPLEXITY: string;
      CREATTIME: string;
      CREATUSER: string;
      MODTIME: string;
      MODUSER: string;
      CREATMODE: string;
    };
    AANBOD: {
      ISINAANBOD: string;
      RISK: string;
      COMMENTAIRE_FR: string;
      COMMENTAIRE_NL: string;
      QTTE_TOTALE: number;
      QTTE_FAITE: number;
      QTTE_REST: number;
      QTTE_MIN: number;
      QTTE_MAX: number;
      MULTIPLE: number;
      DATEVALID_DEBUT: Date;
      DATEVALID_FIN: Date;
      MARKET: string;
      SIPAGENCEFLAG: string;
      SIPCLIENTFLAG: string;
      SIPMINIMUM: number;
      SIPMAXIMUM: number;
      PRIX_MARCHE: number;
      PRIX_CLIENT: number;
    };
    ...


Well, although the solution provided by me in comment works, but it fails on puttin input greater than 999. This can be handled quiet easily. Just do this in template:


<tr>
    <th>SIP maximum</th>
    <td>
       <input id="sipmaximum" name="sipmaximum" type="text" class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="sipmaximum" (focus)="fetchSip()"
        (blur)="formatNumber()" style="width: 70%" required greaterThanZero />
    </td>
 </tr>



and in ts, just change a few things like datatype of sipmaximum and write a method to handle the formatting:


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public sipmaximum: number | string = 9999;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formatNumber();
  }

  public fetchSip(): void {
    this.sipmaximum = +this.sipmaximum;
  }

  public formatNumber(): void {
    this.sipmaximum = (+this.sipmaximum).toFixed(2);
  }
}



This will handle everything and do the job for you buddy! :)
